# Why does "soupe à l'oignon" need the preposition "à"? And why does "soupe de poisson" need "de"?

Tags: prépositions

> « soupe **à** l'oignon »
>
> « soupe **de** poisson »

I want to know why I need to use "à" for one and "de" for the other.

> « soupe à **l'oignon** »
>
> « soupe de **poisson** »

What I also cannot understand is why "oignon" is accompanied by the definite article, but not "poisson"?

Comment: Soupe à l'onion means soup with onions in it. Whereas soupe de poisson is actually a soup made out of fish where the fish is not visible like the onions in the French onion soup. Even though in English, we say French onion soup and fish soup, in French the à la goes means having x in it. Whereas the DE means OUT OF IT. So, soup with onions versus soup made out of fish. We don't make the distinction in English.

Comment: Take a look at the picture: http://www.cuisineactuelle.fr/recettes/soupe-de-poisson-facile-198208 There is no fish visible because it has been ground up.

Comment: @Lambie: L'article [soupe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soupe) de Wikipédia est illustré par une soupe de poisson où les morceaux sont bien visibles. Quand les morceaux ne sont pas visibles, on parle plutôt de _velouté_ ou de _moulinée_, voire de _bisque_ pour les crustacés.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*soupe **à** l'oignon* means *soup **with** onion*, whereas *soupe **de** poisson* refers more to *soup **that is made of** fish*.
If you had *soupe **au** poisson*, it would mean that it's a *soup **with** fish **in it***, and on the opposite if you had *soupe **d'** oignon*, it would be a *soup **which mostly consists of** onion*.

And I guess the article `l'` is here for the same reason, and there is an article in the sentence *soupe **au** poisson* (it has undergone an *elision*, `au` is the contraction of `à le`)

The difference is quite not obvious, even more if French is not your mothertongue.

Can't argue it's like, the classiest language ever, though.

Comment: Indeed you could have (on a restaurant menu): *soupe **de** poisson **à** l'oignon*.

Comment: Usage is king. It's the way it's said. You may find some slight differences in meaning, but those are just "expressions toute faites" (idiomatics).